# Response group members are not updated

Tags: lync-2013

### Lync 2013 Response group members are not updated

I have created Lync2013 Response group using New-CsRgsAgentGroup with -DistributionGroupAddress  parameter but if I will update(add/remove) members from the distribution group the same is not getting reflected in the response group AgentsByUri.

I have also tired to use Update-CsAddressBook and Update-CsUserDatabase but these does not work.

can anyone plese help me to understand the sync mechanism?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to restart the Reponse Goups Services on each Front Ent Server or wait for about 15 minutes, for that type services.msc and find the service